# How do I run update-grub from a LiveCD?

Tags: boot, grub2

Okay, so I did something stupid.  I was trying to clean up my Grub entries, and accidentally removed all of my Linux kernels from Grub (they're still on the hard drive).  So now, obviously, Grub doesn't give me any way to boot into Ubuntu; I can boot into Windows just fine, but Ubuntu isn't even listed.

So I just want to run "sudo upgrade-grub" somehow to restore Ubuntu to the list.  I can boot from a LiveCD, but once there how do I run that command?  (My Ubuntu installation is on sda5, by the way.)

Comment: This works perfectly...did it just 2 days ago- http://opensource-sidh.blogspot.in/2011/06/recover-grub-live-ubuntu-cd.html

Comment: at this thread want to point to - that at 12.10 command update-grub does not work with grub < 2.0 ?! - I myself had last weekend botched up my installation of 12.10 ( pear OS 7.0.1 ) with grub-install and then update-grub was not working - had to do rescue with supergrub-CD ...

Comment: @Nirmik link is dead :(.

Comment: @pevik https://web.archive.org/web/20120427150352/http://opensource-sidh.blogspot.in/2011/06/recover-grub-live-ubuntu-cd.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks for all the great help!  However, in the end nothing seemed to work, and since I had a separate /home partition, I was able to reinstall Ubuntu without losing any data.  I still have to reinstall programs and do some configuring, but everything seems good at this point.

Comment: Glad to know you solved it somehow, but chrooting should have worked, and that, i consider the best solution.

Comment: Yes.  I don't know why it didn't work, but the answer was great (and I upvoted it).  You guys provided lots of help, and perhaps the answers will help someone else get through this problem.

Answer (score 119):

Since you say your grub bootloader appears, but the menu is empty, I think you don't need to reinstall grub, but rather, as you ask, run update-grub. To achieve this, you can use a Live CD, mount the relevant partitions from your hard disk, chroot into the mounted directory, and run update-grub, which should work as if you were operating on the actual hard disk.

Boot with your Live CD, selecting "Try Ubuntu without installing".

Once it boots, open a terminal (ctrl-alt-t) and mount your Ubuntu partition on /mnt. I'm assuming the Ubuntu partition is /dev/sda5, but you should determine this yourself. Let me know if you need help to do this:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
```

Then mount a few more directories that are needed:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
```

Also, if you have a separate Ubuntu boot partition (pretty uncommon these days, but it may be the case):

```
sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt/boot
```

How can you tell if you have a boot partition?

Once you have your Ubuntu partition mounted, open  `/mnt/etc/fstab`. If you see an entry for `/boot`, note which device it is pointing to (`/dev/sda4` maybe?). This is the one you have to mount.

Once these are mounted, do chroot to start using the mounted directory as the root partition:

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

You'll get a `#/` prompt. First thing to do is confirm that you're using the correct `/boot` directory. Go to `/boot/grub` and look at the files there. There should be a bunch of .mod files and a grub.cfg file. If the directory is empty, don't continue, because it means this is NOT your actual `boot` directory. Look above to see how to determine if you need to mount an additional `boot` directory.

Once you've confirmed that `/boot/` contains the correct files, meaning that it *is* the correct location, type:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This should rebuild your /boot/grub/grub.cfg file with the menu entries.

Then exit the chroot:

```
exit
```

At this point you may want to check that things were correctly updated. For this, `cd /mnt/boot/grub` and check that grub's files are there, there should be a bunch of .mod files and grub.cfg, the latter should have entries for your Ubuntu kernels. If you only see grub.cfg and no .mod files, it means that this is NOT the correct boot directory, look above for how to mount a separate boot partition.

Unmount the filesystems:

```
sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt/sys
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/boot #Only if you mounted it earlier
sudo umount /mnt/
```

And then reboot, hopefully your Grub menu will be restored.

Comment: When I try to run the three mount commands, I get "mount point /mnt/dev does not exist" or the corresponding one for each.

Comment: is your Ubuntu install on /dev/sda5? If so, after `sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt` you should be able to `cd /mnt` and see your Ubuntu installation's tree there. It should have dev, sys and proc. If not, maybe you're mounting the wrong partition. Can you check this? Thanks!

Comment: I restarted the LiveCD and this time it appears to be working.  I must have typed something wrong the first time, although I was careful.  Anyway, I'm rebooting now ... and no, nothing has changed.  Still no choice of Ubuntu in the Grub menu.

Comment: So to answer your question, after running "sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt", and then "cd /mnt", I do see dev, sys, and proc.

Comment: Updated the answer with some things to check to ensure changes were correctly made. If you see your Ubuntu entries in grub.cfg, but still nothing in the menu, I'm not sure what may be happening :/

Comment: After mounting everything, and running chroot and getting the #/ prompt, I try running "sudo update-grub".  I get "sudo: unable to resolve host unbuntu" but then it goes ahead and generates grub.cfg.  It lists the various kernels it finds ("Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic" for one), but it doesn't really seem to update it, as when I reboot I still have no Ubuntu in the Grub menu.

Comment: look at the verification step, before unmounting /mnt, go into /mnt/boot/grub and ensure that grub.cfg was created there, it contains entries for Ubuntu kernels *and* that other grub files are present. Let me know.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3635/discussion-between-kelley-and-roadmr)

Comment: Sorry to drag you into chat, but a message appeared saying the discussion was too long. I'll try not to keep you.
The only Grub files there are grub.cfg and grubenv. I don't see any entries in grub.cfg for any kernel entries.  (I also posted this in chat.)

Comment: You Sir, are a life-saver :) Thanks for this. Worked like a charm.

Comment: This saved my life! By happen chance sda5 was my ubuntu partition. Could you please explain, or point me to, how one determines which sda# would be the correct partition?

Comment: @Jay: The way to know for sure is to mount each partition of type `Linux` and search for files you know should be in `/` (such as `bin/` or sbin). It really depends on how you partitioned your HD when installing. If you chose basic partitioning, a sure-fire way is to run (from the Live CD, right before mounting `sda5`) this command: `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`. Partitions are shown on the very left. The root partition is usually the biggest (look at `Blocks` column) with type `Linux` (look at the `System` column at the very right).

Comment: this worked perfectly for me. mounting /dev was the missing thing!

Comment: You need `sudo mount --bind /run /mnt/run` as well to fix the error `/run/lock/lvm: mkdir failed: Too many levels of symbolic links`

Comment: Does anyone know if this same scenario would work when plugging the main hard drive of the computer I want to update grub (say computer A) as an external drive onto another computer (computer B), and executing all these commands from B before putting hard drive back in A? I cannot use neither my keyboard nor my screen on computer A and I'd like to update grub to boot automatically into ubuntu.

Comment: Note that for people using UEFI, you need to mount the uefi partition into /boot/efi, like `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /boot/efi`. And eventually if you adden't any entry installed before (or anyway you can always do that without any problem), you can run `grub-install /dev/sda` before the `grub-update`.

Comment: Some more details about this technique, esp. about setups with **software RAID, LVM and bcache**, are here in the Ubuntu community wiki: [Grub2 → Installing → Reinstalling Grub2 → via chroot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_ChRoot).

Comment: @Kelley, this should be the accepted answer...

Comment: no need to unmount. make sure you open Multiple root terminals and just reboot from another terminal thats not chroot

Comment: Maybe this is lost on the many comments already present, but I had to use `grub-install /dev/sdX` and 
`grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX` before `update-grub` following https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd Thanks for this answer it set me on the right track to finish my move from HDD to SSD. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't see any `.mod` files but it still worked without mounting `/boot` separately.

Answer (score 17):

Boot from a Live CD.

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and run following commands:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
```

Install the GRUB2 boot loader:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

That’s `/dev/sda` — the hard disk itself, not the Ubuntu partition – `/dev/sda5`.

Unmount the Ubuntu partition and restart the computer like so:

```
sudo umount /dev/sda5 ; sudo reboot
```

If you have more than one OS installed, re-detect OSes like so:

```
sudo update-grub
```

That’s it!

Comment: flagged mine for deletion - no point in the same thing twice

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work.  It reinstalls Grub, but when I reboot it still hasn't been updated, so my Ubuntu installation still doesn't show up in Grub.  Somehow I need to update Grub before I reboot, like from the LiveCD.

Comment: @Kelley Are you sure Ubuntu installation is on sda5? You can check it by running `sudo fdisk -l`. Ubuntu installation will have a `*` after /dev/sdxx.

Comment: Yes, it's on sda5.  However, the * is after sda2, which is my Windows partition (and the last partition into which I've been able to boot, since it's the only choice on my Grub menu).

Comment: Chroot. Please read other answers.

Comment: @BasharatSial : Why would you install grub onto a Windows partition?

Comment: And we got, which was expected: `/usr/sbin/grub-probe:error:failed to get canonical path of /cow.`.

Answer (score 3):

In 2022, you probably have an EFI system that requires a couple more steps.

Boot from a Live CD and open the terminal.

Mount the partition (e.g. `/dev/sda5`) with your original OS to `/mnt`:

```sh
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
```

In case you are using a SSD disk, the device name starts with *nvme*, e.g. `/dev/nvme0n1`.

Find out which partition has the EFI system:

```sh
fdisk -l /dev/sda | grep EFI
# example output:
# /dev/sda1           2048     309247    307200   150M EFI System
```

Mount the EFI system partition (e.g. `/dev/sda1`) to `/mnt/boot/efi`:

```sh
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
```

Install GRUB according to @basharat-sialvi's instructions:

```sh
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

Finally, reboot the system.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to that problem was:

1. download supergrub2disk from
   http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/supergrub2diskdownload/super-grub2-disk-stable/
2. put it on the pendrive
   http://www.supergrubdisk.org/put-super-grub2-disk-into-an-usb-pendrive-as-an-iso-image-from-windows/
3. boot computer from pendrive with supergrub2disk on it
4. log in to your Ubuntu
5. get Boot-Repair for Ubuntu from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Maybe it's not the fastest solution but for me it was the easiest one.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is the exact same as roadmr's answer except much easier.

1. Boot into AntiX Live CD.
2. Menu>Applications>System Tools>Boot Repair
3. Select 'Repair GRUB Configuration file' (this option does run update-grub)
4. Select the **drive/partition** where /boot resides
5. Reboot when its finished.

In my particular case, 'Reinstall GRUB Bootloader' fixed it for me.. I have a dual-boot windows/linux setup.  I used Macrium 7 to create a clone of a drive to a file.  Then restore that file to a new drive.  After I restored it to the new drive, it would boot to a [black screen with a blinking cursor in the upper left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ly6T.png).

Answer (score 0):

The combined instructions of [roadmr](https://askubuntu.com/a/145253/293759) and [Basharat Sialvi](https://askubuntu.com/a/145246/293759) can be found here:
https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/293759

Instructions for chainloader and multiboot commands of Grub2 are at [Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2%20Other%20Os#Chain_Loading).