# Accidentally set GRUB_TIMEOUT=0, cannot boot into Ubuntu now

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, windows, startup

I have a dual boot system of Ubuntu 12.10 and Windows 7. Stupidly, I set my default boot OS to Windows 7 using [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader) and set `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`. Now when I boot, the Ubuntu red/purple screen flashes on and off and proceeds with booting Windows 7, effectively locking me out of Ubuntu.

Is there any way to:

1. Change the "booter?" to Windows 7, which would not have the timeout.
2. Hold down a key to over-ride the timeout? I've already tried shift without success.
3. [This link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1650021) is exactly the problem I've been having, however I don't completely understand the part about booting from a live cd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can boot from an Ubuntu live CD. And then follow the instructions given in the [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1650021).

The idea behind using a live CD is to give you access to Linux partition via terminal. Earlier you changed the Grub configuration, You need to do it again. But you cannot (easily) do it from Windows.

So the easy way is to use Ubuntu Live and then when you boot in to it, use the terminal to edit the **/etc/default/grub** file.

Update the grub so that changes are taken into effect: update-grub

Comment: Booted from a usb Ubuntu installer, selected "Try Ubuntu", and referred to this question to run `update-grub`: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd

Comment: Editing `/etc/default/grub` on the current installation solely isn't going to help. As Joel pointed out, you need to run `update-grub` too, after a successful chroot into the installation.

Answer (score 3):

Does <kbd>Esc</kbd> work for you? Also note that you have to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> down for a while before the menu appears.

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Comment: Just tried `Esc` but to no avail.