# Do I need to run grub update after cloing my Ubuntu partition to my new ssd?

Tags: grub2, updates

I am relatively new to Ubuntu, been using 12.04 LTS for a few months. I have it installed on a 160GB Seagate rotating media drive dual booting with Windows Vista and all has been going well.
I recently installed a 120GB Kingston HyperX ssd and used Clonezilla to clone the Ubuntu partition to the ssd. This worked fine and with only the Kingston connected I can boot to it with no issues.

Ultimately I intend to boot from the Kingston ssd and use the Seagate for data, occasionally booting to Vista. (Leaving the original Ubuntu installation on the Seagate as a backup)

When my pc starts up I hit esc to get the boot menu, choose the Kingston, get the grub menu and intermittently it appears to actually start from the Seagate; I know this because I can hear the disk being accessed as well as seeing the space available for Ubuntu in system monitor.

With only the Kingston connected Ubuntu starts fine so I know it functions -  but with the Seagate also connected I think Ubuntu is getting confused at the grub menu, sometimes starting from the Seagate and sometimes the Kingston.

My question is (aside from nuking the Ubuntu installation on the Seagate) do you think I need to run grub update, with only the Kingston connected, to let the system reorient itself to it's new home?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think it was happened, Cloning results two partitions with same UUID. So Grub while booting or OS while mounting can't distinguish between them.

1. Boot using live CD or USB key.
2. Unmount any auto-mounted partition.
3. Open terminal, run `sudo fdisk -l` to see your SSD partition device path.
4. Generate new UUID for SSD cloned partition (seem `/dev/sda1` in your case)

   ```
   tune2fs /dev/sdxy -U random
   ```
5. Copy that UUID from:

   ```
   sudo blkid /dev/sdxy
   ```

   Mount SSD partition (/dev/sda1), edit `/etc/fstab` to update old UUID with to new one:

   ```
   sudo nano /media/ssd_part/etc/fstab
   ```

   `/media/ssd_part/` is where it is mounted.

   Change old UUID with copied one in the line for root `/`. **Example**:

   ```
   # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
   #
   # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
   # device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
   # that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
   #
   # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
   # / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
   UUID=4c0c4c6d-708b-45b0-b9e9-a5e6a7de491e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
   # /media/sneetsher/gnu_files/ was on /dev/sda5 during installation
   UUID=bf958b50-c15a-45fd-b946-36ab1612045b /media/sneetsher/gnu_files/ ext4    defaults        0       2
   # swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
   UUID=d15727d5-78c2-4a46-aa67-66895d7f6371 none            swap    sw              0       0
   ```

   In this **example**, See this line which have mount point is `/`

   ```
    UUID=4c0c4c6d-708b-45b0-b9e9-a5e6a7de491e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
   ```
6. Reinstall Grub on SSD

   ```
   sudo grub-install --root-directory=/media/ssd_part /dev/sdx
   ```

At this point grub on SSD is aware of all OS's. Whereas grub in HDD is still don't list Ubuntu from SSD.

If each drive has a partition with boot flag. BIOS gonna boot 1st drive in boot order list. So if you booted from old HDD, update its grub.

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Then both drives have grub with all OS's listed.

Comment: re: step #4 - am I keying in that command as is or substituting a partition for 'sdxy' (my ssd has 3 partitions: /dev/sda1, /dev/sda2, /dev/sda5, linux, extended & linux swap respectively)

Comment: cont'd...re: step #5 - copy=copy to clipbrd? does the 'sudo nano' cmd relate to changing the old uuid? do I key that cmd in as is? Not clear as to what that cmd will do; is the 'sudo nano' cmd a separate step? re: step #6 - do I key the cmd in as is or substitute an actual dev path? Tx

Comment: step4: `/dev/sda1` in your case. step5: I have update answer see if it is clear

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to change UUID of the old partition and leave configuration files alone?

Comment: Yeah, you can change UUID of the old partition. But if you need as ready to go backup, its `/etc/fstab` should be updated with its new UUID. So same steps either side. Or you have other better idea, I hope you share it.

Comment: @aap , I miss to mention for notification sorry.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet. Shouldn't all uuids on the ssd be changed since they are clones? Tx.

Comment: Yeah, just don't forget to update its `fstab` with new UUID's

Comment: Booted from live cd...tried mounting/unmounting b4 changing uuid but couldn't get partition mounted; I don't understand the mount cmd syntax. Looking up info on mount cmd did little to help; will keep trying 'til it makes sense. Turns out just two uuids conflict so I thought I'd change the one on the hdd (/dev/sdb5) after I figure out the mount cmd. Is it possible to 'update' grub or does it have to be reinstalled?

Comment: yes, you can update grub but it's more longer. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd#145253

Comment: I successfully chgd the uuid, updated fstab and the ssd grub but my ssd grub won't boot to the hdd partition; does boot to Vista & ssd ubuntu. The hdd grub still doesn't work so it did not install. I used 'sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdb'. (I had mounted /dev/sdb5 on /mnt). It's not imperative that I boot to the hdd ubuntu but curious that it won't since the ssd grub sees it!?! Per updated ssd grub: Found Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (12.04) on /dev/sdb5