# Dual install problems

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I realize this question has been asked by others but I can't seem to find a fix to my problem. 
I had Ubuntu 13.10 dual-installed with Windows 8. Everything was working perfectly, until I accepted the update to Windows 8.1. Now I can't boot into Ubuntu unless I reboot from the disk. I know Ubuntu is still installed because all of my personal settings and programs are still in place. But I want to have the option of which OS to boot at startup like I used to. (Is this the "grub" menu?) I've tried many suggestions with no success. Let me clarify, I'm new to programming/etc. Frankly, the answer I need may have already been posted but I just don't understand it. Who knows.
I initially installed according to the instructions here: http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html

When repair suggestions didn't work I tried re-entering the terminal commands at the end of the instructions at the above website. After re-entering those commands, boot repair gave me the following:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7225235/
The boot files of [The OS now in use - Ubuntu 13.10] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https: //help.ubuntu .com/community/BootPartition)
You may want to retry after deactivating the [Backup and rename Windows EFI files] option.

Hopefully, this is enough information for someone out there to know what's going on and give me a solution.
Thank you in advance for any and all assistance in this matter. Please keep in mind, as I said, I'm learning but I'm still new to the whole programming world so try to give me a break on the jargon if you can. Granted I can do more research to understand if necessary. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the windows update has overwritten your grub.
Try this: [How do I run update-grub from a LiveCD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd)
If it doesn't work, installing Ubuntu again is often the fastest solution, unless you want to learn how to fix this problems properly...

Comment: From my research, I figured it must have overwritten the grub, like you said, but I had no idea for sure or how to fix it. I definitely want to learn but right now I just need Ubuntu back. (stupid Windows) I'll check the link and re-install if necessary. Thank you so much for your help!!!