# Attempted to dual boot with Windows and now can only run Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, 14.04, windows

Very recently, I decided to attempt to dual boot Ubuntu with my already installed windows 8. Everything worked perfectly, I manually set up disk partitions (this is all on 1 hard drive), and it loaded up Ubuntu fine. HOWEVER, now when I try to load up my computer it only has 2 options in the boot menu and both just load up Windows (both were something related to hard disk). I also can only boot from legacy hard disk things. (I already only was able to aside from my USB that I installed Windows from)

The Windows files are still accessible from Ubuntu, but I cannot just load Windows. There is no option to. I also don't have the 2 buttons for each operating system I was expecting. I can only select the thing to load from BIOS.

So, my question is, how do I load the Windows partition on my hard drive? I'm sorry if I'm a bit clueless I am just new to both Linux and dual-booting.

Comment: Try looking at this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
Run Boot-repair from a LiveCD.
This may help too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd

Comment: Did the repair-boot program work, or the update-grub? (for my curiosity)

Comment: Repair boot, although it actually also updated grub. In the 2 hours I've had Ubuntu I'm already starting to get familiar with it and like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to install boot-repair.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Be patient and follow the instructions.  Now Grub2 will let you boot windows.

Comment: This was already answered by No Time in the comments, but I'm accepting it anyway as it is correct.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't see those comments.  My bad:(

Comment: Just so you know BAMF this will not work for every version (this is off the Ubuntu forum) if you are not using "Trusty"(14.04) you will install the wrong list, and could mess up stuff, you can bypass this by doing Tabto  autocomplete.. but you have to know what the command is doing. The answer for the most part is good, and works for this version :)