# Booting in single user mode

Tags: sudo, grubrescue, single-user

On 14.10 holding shift at boot time doesn't bring up the grub menu. Is there another way I can boot in single user mode?

I have bricked my sudoers file so I can't use sudo btw.

I don't get a grub menu as I only have one OS on my machine.

I have tried changing every combination of boot types in the BIOS.

Comment: You will need to add more details to your question.  Why you should need to hold shift key?  The grub menu should appear on its own at boot.

Comment: do you dual boot?

Comment: Yes, I do.  If you have only Ubuntu installed and trying to get the grub menu, probably there is some other key than SHIFT.

Comment: I a pinch, use a installation/rescue disk to boot. You can easily adapt http://askubuntu.com/a/145253/16395

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I tried tapping both shift keys really fast on a system boot. This would only bring up the menu about one time in five. I think it's because the mohterboard is so new and so very fast at getting to the bootloader stage.

Then I chose to go into rescue mode and then from the menu when to a root prompt.

After getting a root prompt I did the usual..

```
 # mount -o remount,rw
```

Once the file system is in rw mode I then edited to the sudoers file.

## Leasons learned

- Always use visudo to edit your sudoers file so that syntax is checked for you before saving.

> ```
>  # sudo visudo
> ```

- Annoying, ubuntu uses nano as it's default text editor, which put me off using visudo. So another good tip is to change your default editor by using  update-alternatives

> ```
> # sudo update-alternatives --config editor
> ```

- It's probably a good idea to set a password (a very secure one obviously) for root.