# I Have Downloaded Ubuntu. Now Want to Install Directly From HDD

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7

Well my question is unique. Because I want to know how can I install Ubuntu from HDD or a USB while the answer provided within the link someone said is duplicate is actually on how one can install Ubuntu from a DVD. I don't have any blank DVD to burn. So I want to install Ubuntu DIRECTLY from HDD mainly. But if it is not possible then I can install from USB too.

I am completely new in Linux world. Just want to taste Ubuntu as I listened lots of sweet words about it. However I just downloaded

```
ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-i386.iso
```

My machine is processor Intel 2.50GH core i5, Intel main board, 2GB RAM, 500GB HDD. I am using windows 7 on C:\ drive. I want dual booting. Existing windows 7 with Ubuntu ubuntu-14.04.2. Can anyone tell me....

1- How can I install Ubuntu on Drive J:\ so that I will get dual booting.

Ubuntu with Windows 7?

2- Alternatively I can install from a USB too. Can you tell how to install from USB?

Comment: If you want you can test Ubuntu from USB without installing it. Here you can see how to make bootable USB: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows And by the way, this question was answered many times...

Comment: I won't downvote this because, to be fair, it took me 2 mins to find the duplicate. That is such a bad title...

Comment: Did you actually look at the link  provided by @Jacajack ? I would start there and finish with the link Provided by Tim. Just substitute the phrase "usb stick" for dvd and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are specific instructions on the Ubuntu website, but here you go.

To install Ubuntu from a USB drive:

1. Run `defrag` from the Start Menu (search it) to defragment your hard drive.
2. Download [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) and use it to burn the ISO to your USB drive.
3. Boot from the USB drive. If you tell me the brand of your computer, I can tell you what to press to enter the boot menu upon startup.
4. Once the setup window for Ubuntu appears, select `Try Ubuntu`.
5. Hit the <kbd>WINDOWS</kbd> key and search for `Gparted`.
6. Use Gparted to shrink your Windows 7 volume and then create an ext4 partition in the free space.
7. Start the setup from the launcher.
8. When you get to the step where you are asked where to install Ubuntu, choose `Something Else` and select the partition you just created.
   Ubuntu should now install.

By the way, installing from a DVD is exactly the same as USB, just slower.

Comment: nice info. Well isn't there any way to install directly from HDD? If not then USB is fine too. Asking just for curiosity.

Comment: @MikeFriedman It is possible to install from  the hard drive, but it's not the safest way to install, nor is it reliable.

Comment: No problem! Tell me. I want to learn. :)

Comment: @mikefriedman I'm not even sure how. Ubuntu's Windows executable asks you to reboot and install when you open it, but I think it fails upon reboot unless it's some external media.

Comment: I have some relevant questions....

1- What should be the size of the drive where Ubuntu will be installed?
2- If I install it on drive J:\ will it be any problem?
3- At this moment my Windows 7 is on C:\ and when I boot I see a screen with few options. 1 is Ubuntu(I installed Ubuntu 13 from an old CD but never used frequently). Another one is windows 7. Now if I delete the drive where my old Ubuntu is installed from windows disk management tool will it effect my boot sector and my computer will crash on next booting? If so then what should I do to avoid the problem when deleting the drive?

Comment: well no problem. I will install from USB. Just let me know about the questions I just asked?

Comment: @MikeFriedman 1. If I remember correctly Ubuntu install takes about 1.5GB or so on USB, I usually use 4GB stick and use the free space for a persistance partition, in case you need some files, and it works perfectly. 2.If drive J has nothing important shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: 3. Don't delete from Disk Management, Just install the new Ubuntu over the old one, In the Ubuntu installer when you choose the Manual partition option you can erase the old partition and create new ones for / and swap. Make sure the boot loader is installed on the same drive as before (you can get it from the bios/efi) otherwise it can do some wonky stuff. If you have an issue with grub (bootloader) not rebuilding the entries try this workaround http://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd