# How to triple boot windows and two linux distros

Tags: dual-boot

I just got a new pc and installed windows 10 and I am a big linux fan so of course I setup dual boot with ubuntu 15.10 but I would also like to setup linux mint. I have checked out other questions like this but they all start without ubuntu installed. Is it still possible for me to add another distro after I have installed ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

> Just install normally. You can boot from your USB and follow the steps
>   of the installer. You can either create a partition manually before
>   installing or use the tools provided by the Mint installer to
>   partition during the installation process.
>
> The only thing you really have to worry about is when the installer
>   asks you whether to install a boot loader (GRUB). Then, you have 2
>   choices. Since you already have a GRUB installed by Ubuntu, you can
>   either choose to not install a new one from mint and use Ubuntu's or
>   you can install Mint's and overwrite Ubuntu's.
>
> A) Use the existing GRUB.
>
> When the installer asks you whether to install a boot loader, say no.
>   Once the installation has finished, reboot and load Ubuntu (Mint will
>   not appear in the list of available OSs). From Ubuntu, refresh GRUB so
>   it will detect your new Mint installation:
>
> sudo update-grub
>   
> B) Use Mint's GRUB.
>
> When the installer asks you whether to install a boot loader, say yes.
>   Make sure you install it in the same location where your Ubuntu's GRUB
>   was installed. This will probably be the master boot record (MBR) of
>   your primary hard drive. Reboot and you should now have Mint's GRUB
>   installed and will be able to choose Mint, Ubuntu or Windows.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155396/how-to-have-triple-boot-linux-mint-17-cinnamon-ubuntu-14-04-windows-8

Answer (score 1):

make partition for new distro and install, should be fine. after install update grub

you can update grub without rebooting to ubuntu by using chroot, like here

[link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd)

also you probably could edit /etc/fstab to have same /home mount point in every linux installation, but i wouldn't do that, something could go very wrong :)

Comment: Assuming both are either UEFI or both BIOS, just be sure to install in same boot mode. I have multiple Ubuntu installs and use about 25GB for / (root) but have large data partitions. When I still had XP years ago, I used NTFS as a data partition. Windows 8 or later makes it a bit more difficult as you must have fast startup off or even a data partition is still mounted with the hibernation(fast start).

Answer (score 0):

Install Ubuntu first with a partition (Remember your UEFI permissions) then after that instalation Mint will ask you if you would like to install alongside windows and mint, if not use the "something else" partition