# black screen after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, system-installation, uefi

Hopefully this has an easy solution. I recently installed Ubuntu using the Ubiquity installer for the latest release. Due to my hardware, in order to install it from my USB, i had to use the `nomodeset` parameter. If i don't use `nomodeset`, i get a black screen before installation.

Using `nomodeset` to live boot / install Ubuntu worked great. I didn't get a black screen, and it said that the Ubuntu installation completed successfully with no errors. I installed Ubuntu on a 500 GB SSD.

now, after the install was done, it prompted me to restart my computer like always. So I did, and after I restart, I get a black screen. I presume that I am getting a black screen for the same reason that I was before I used `nomodeset`, because after it installed it is currently not set to boot using the `nomodeset` parameter. I'm in UEFI mode (I installed it in UEFI mode) and I tried fixing this by changing to Legacy mode, but that didn't work.

How would I fix this? I have my computer set to boot to the SSD that I installed Ubuntu to from the Bios menu, but whenever I boot it, I get a black screen. There's no terminal or any place where I can enter anything, it's just black. How would I set Ubuntu to boot using `nomodeset` after it's installed, that way I can see my desktop and then install my Nvidia drivers? 
?

EDIT: Other posts suggest to press SHIFT right after the BIOS splash screen, and then edit nomodeset parameter into the grub options. When I press SHIFT, the grub menu doesn't show up. Does this mean something did go wrong in the installation even though I got no errors and it completed successfully? I can't boot it using nomodeset by pressing SHIFT right when it boots. Any other options?

EDIT2: Since using SHIFT doesn't work, could I set it to boot with nomodeset by editing grub before I install it????

Comment: Do the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/38834) help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: What I found from research was to hold the SHIFT button, but I do it and nothing happens, it's still a black screen. Am I not doing it early enough, perhaps?

Comment: Wait a few minutes after it goes to a blank screen and try Ctrl+Alt+F1. Does that bring up a login screen?

Comment: @Olathe no it doesn't

Comment: Does [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/145253) help? Keep in mind that, just before running `sudo update-grub`, you should use `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and add `nomodeset` after `quiet splash`. It should be within the double quotes, not after them.

Comment: You can edit grub from a live session using your installation usb.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by using Ubuntu boot repair from a live CD. This fixed grub, and I was able to then boot ubuntu from my SSD using nomodeset.

Answer (score 0):

You can add those parameters to the kernel command line in `/etc/default/grub` by running a live session with your installation usb and chrooting into your OS. That will allow you to run `update-grub` so you can reboot with the needed parameters. Just follow the directions in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/145253/381089