# Resized windows partition now stuck in grub rescue

Tags: grub2

Exactly as the title says. I resized my windows partition and now I cant access Ubuntu or Windows. Goes straight to grub rescue. Tried multiple methods but I'm stuck with a faulty live usb that fails to reinstall ubuntu. Any ideas?

Comment: [Try this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd).