# Ubuntu 16 won't dual boot with Kali

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, partitioning, kali

I installed Kali Linux on 1 partition and after that I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on the other one but when I start my PC , the only boot option is "Kali-grub" or "advanced options for kali ".

When I load Kali and open the Linux partition I can see that the Ubuntu is installed on it.

Please tell me how can I boot it (i checked in Disks and it says that the partition is Bootable ).

Comment: boot from a live media and repair grub. This covers it  (disregard the word Windows): https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: @ElderGeek This is what I get when I run `grub-install /dev/sda3`

 installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
P.S. Can't fix it with live version, when I boot installation USB it just runs setup

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are trying to install grub in a partition rather than on the MBR of the drive? As in `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` Perhaps this link is more useful in your situation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Comment: @ElderGeek  Can I somehow e-mail or pm you ? I want to have dual boot for Kali and Ubuntu, where should i install grub?

Comment: @DavidMarjanovic You should install it to the MBR: `/dev/sda`

Comment: @AndroidDev I have sda1-5 , should i just type `/dev/sda` ?

Comment: @DavidMarjanovic - Yes

Comment: @AndroidDev nope , I did `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` and `reboot` but still no Ubuntu in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Ubuntu isn't showing up as a boot option on the menu you need to update grub before installing it as described [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd/145253#145253) after that you should install grub to the MBR of your boot drive with the command `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`

or from within the system that boots issue the commands:

```
sudo os-prober
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: See the comments, that didn't work for OP

Comment: @AndroidDev Saw the comments. Don't see where grub was updated prior to installation.

Comment: I thought it updates when you install it?

Comment: @AndroidDev  Nope.  the configuration update is a separate process. There is even a cool project for tweaking GRUB here:https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer

Comment: Can I somehow install some Ubuntu boot loader  and how do I do that (Kali is rolling )

Comment: @ElderGeek I did `update-grub` i got this
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.3.0-kali1-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.3.0-kali1-amd64
Found Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (16.04) on /dev/sda3
done

As you can se Ubuntu is on /dev/sda3 i did `grub-install /dev/sda`
now i will reboot

Comment: Happy days are here

Comment: @ElderGeek Can confirm that it know shows Ubuntu as an option , tnx a lot man but still some problems when I load it (graphics,probably some drivers)  , thanks a lot once again

Comment: I would search for answers to those other problems here. There are thousands of them. If my answer worked for you please upvote and/or accept it so that others with your problem can find solutions. Regards.