# Black screen at the startup

Tags: 18.04, screen

Ubuntu gives black screen at startup. I  have no idea why.  Maybe it's the  software update I did yesterday? Why is it happening?

Comment: additional information: ı added kali Linux sources list from katoolin and installed armitage-msfconsole-postgresql

Comment: Please examine [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018714/black-screen-after-installing-katoolin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018714/black-screen-after-installing-katoolin)

Comment: Also see [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018441/how-do-i-restore-my-system-os-back-to-its-original-condition-after-attempting-to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018441/how-do-i-restore-my-system-os-back-to-its-original-condition-after-attempting-to)

Comment: apt get update and apt get update is not working  (unable to fetch data)deleted kali Linux repos still the same

Comment: alsın there is two linuxes in grub loader one is 18.0 with kali3-amd64 and one is 15.0 generic both are not working

Comment: when I try to install drivers it says you held broken packages  when I try to apt update says some index files failed to download

Answer (score -1):

the answer is firstly press e continuously or just press e after the splash screen when you are in grub loader press advanced options and select your primary version and go to recovery mode of that version (maybe its the kernel version I Just saying it linux version) and don't forget to enable your networking I Didn't see the big button  there because of that half of the command won't work.
just do a apt-get update and apt-get upgrade after that when you in the black screen press ctrl+alt+f2 after the text-based login screen appeared type your password and your problem is solved but sadly it's a not complete solution I Guess you have to do press ctrl+alt+f2 everytime you boot up but hey at least ubuntu opens right have a good day