# GRUB not loading after Windows 10 reinstall

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, grubrescue, 17.04

I have recently reinstalled windows 10 in my Ubuntu/Windows dual boot laptop. After that, GRUB bootloader is not loading up. It straight goes booting up the Windows.

I saw a couple of blogs suggesting `boot-repair`. I did that and it's still not loading. Help.

Comment: I solved same problem recently in my desktop by [reinstalling grub](https://askubuntu.com/a/145246/517858).

Comment: It's even not getting mounted on the linux partition.

Comment: You must boot some live Linux disto and mount your partition manually, install GRUB to it (according to previous link), then reboot computer and GRUB should work.

Comment: I exactly did that. Did a boot from a usb stick, used gparted to identify the partition and then tried to mount that. It gives out an error "not a valid partition".

Comment: Did you try changing the bootloader to grub in the BIOS.

Comment: Can you paste here, which command did you exactly use?

Comment: I did sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt

Comment: So maybe /dev/sda3 isn't valid partition..

Comment: It is. I checked it using the gparted. It's an ext4 partition with a Ubuntu 17.04 installation. That's why I'm so curious to know what's going on.

Comment: What returns `lsblk`?

Comment: I already reinstalled Ubuntu to solve the issue. So...

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my bad english! :) it is because when you install windows after linux(ubuntu) the windows loader takes places on the hard disk, to do: It consists of booting thanks to Super Grub2 Disk. Once in your system you will recover GRUB with a simple command. http://www.supergrubdisk.org/ download this file and then boot then in a usb or disk,  then boot this from the boot options or bios then in the super grub2 select:

Detect any os
your Ubuntu (you have to select it from the list of detected OS)
Once you have started in your distribution you will open a console and load the Grub in the MBR by executing the following command:

Grub-install / dev / sda when sda is your hard disk!

if you want to read this in spanish and more detailed, http://www.guia-ubuntu.com/index.php/Recuperar_GRUB