# Blinking Cursor After GPU (AMD) Removal - No Grub Menu

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, cursor, gpu-driver

after a lot of googling and failing I am now seeking help from you professionals!

Short summery:

I used to have a working dual boot with Linux and Win10 using a Radeon R9 Nano.
After returning from a longer travel, I decided to get rid of my R9 Nano, which the system was running with. Removing that from the system did work well for Win10 so far. In order to have a cleaner cable management, after removing the GPU, I unplugged my SSDs (1 for Linux, 1 for Windows) and propably shitched their connectors. For a while now I was only using windows (due to autoboot that SSD), which did not give me any trouble so far.

But trying to boot that Linux SSD now, throws me at a blinking cursor with no possibility to see grub or boot linux whatsoever. When I press any key while that blinking cursor the next boot device is booted (let it be a USB-Stick or Win10).

So in conclusion, I can boot a Livestick and Win10 but not my Linux installation nor Grub itself. Besides I did not uninstall the AMD driver in linux, I assume the main problem might be a false Grub installation, since that drives may have swapped (sda/sdb/sdc ... - I have a HDD installed for data storage as well). So all my linux partitions lay on that one SSD (seperate /home and /swap).

Do you guys have a some hints or tipps, how I can repair grub or whatever again, to use my linux installation again?? That would be absolutely fantastic!

Thank you so far for reading my problem. Hope to hear from you.

Ruphus

Comment: Maybe, you need to reinstall grub with Live USB, if I understood your problem correctly?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try and report back, if I was able to fix it.

Comment: I try to follow those instrucitons in the post for repairing grub, but as I just noticed, I only have a /boot/EFI/ folder. Because of that my installations seems to differ strong from the information in that post. How do I repair that /boot/EFI installation? /boot/EFI contains the folders "Boot" "Microsoft" "ubuntu" .... "ubuntu" again contains the "grub.cfg" ans a couple of .efi files....

Comment: I just wanted to let you know, that I was able to solve the problem using the "Boot-Repair-Tool" as a liveStick. The problem was obviously not the GPU driver rather than the falsy partition assignment. http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/boot-repair-tool-repair-the-most-boot-related-problems