# What partitions are required for Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, 18.04

I've been unsuccessfuly partitioning for a while, so what partitions do I need? I'm running a rather old device, with these specs as follows: 3.7 GB ram, Intel Core 13-3220 CPU, Intel Ivybridge Desktop graphics card, GNOME 3.28.2, 64 bits, and a 500.1 GB hard drive (500,107 MB). I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, and I would be very grateful if someone could tell me the size, primary/logical, mount point and what it's used as. I am a complete beginner, so I don't know anything, so it would help tremendously if I could get some direction. Thanks!

Comment: For such a small HDD, just let the Ubuntu installer do the partitioning for you. Partitioning requires some advanced knowledge of hard disk structure and Ubuntu workings.

Comment: That's what I tried at first, I just went with regular install, but upon boot, it would say Error 1962: No OS found, even though it would prompt to erase ubuntu off of the hard drive upon subsequent installations, so I have to partition differently to get it to boot.

Comment: If you boot the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, are you able to use "Try Ubuntu"? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll probably miss them.

Comment: Did you create your HDD with a MBR or GPT partition table?

Comment: Just curious... how do you know that you've got `GNOME 3.28.2`?

Comment: @heynnema I am able try Ubuntu from a live usb. When I go to details in settings, it says I have GNOME 3.28.2.

Comment: Assuming that Ubuntu is going to be your only OS on this HDD, boot Ubuntu Live, start gparted, (and since you've got an I3, I'll assume it's UEFI/EFI), go to the gparted menu and install a new GPT partition table on the HDD (this WILL wipe the drive), then quit gparted, and double-click the `Install Ubuntu` icon that you see on the desktop. See if it works this time. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema That didn't work :(

Comment: Then try a MBR partition table. Report back.

Comment: How do I get to the MBR table?

Comment: Same place that you got to the GPT partition table. gparted. If you don't see MBR there, they may call it DOS.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I got to GPT before by going through the installation and selecting something else, and idk how to switch from that to MBR. Sorry for all the confusion, but how do I access MBR? Like is it a command in the terminal, do i just go through the normal installation, etc.?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, use `gparted`, `Device` menu. `Create partition table`. Choose GPT or MBR (or DOS, if MBR is not there).

Comment: @heynnema There's no DOS or MBR. The closest thing is msdos. The options that pop up are: atari, aix, amiga, bsd, dvh, gpt, mac, msdos, pc98, sun, loop.

Comment: Use msdos. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema That didn't work either

Comment: Is this a Lenovo? [SOLVED] Error 1962: No operating system found. Lenovo K430  only boot Ubuntu, rename files
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2243715

Comment: Reinstall as GPT partition table, and then try @oldfred file renaming tip.

Comment: do you get errors about inability to install bootloader duing the installation?

Comment: @oldfred It is a lenovo. How do I rename those files?

Comment: @ptetteh227 The installation runs smoothly, but upon rebooting the system it doesn't boot whatsoever.

Comment: Boot-Repair now does the copy of shimx64 to bootx64 automatically. But grub also now installs a copy to /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi which should be a hard drive or fallback entry in your UEFI boot menu. But if only booting Ubuntu, you can make description read "Windows Boot Manager", but boot with grub or shim see post #17 & http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 and option IV.

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a primary partition with the Ubuntu installation. Mount point is / .  I don't like to skimp on the size of the disk so at a minimum I would give it 40G in space, and more if you want to do a lot of stuff on it. . .  Also a swap partition of size of 1G would do, but it wouldn't hurt to give it more (try 4G). . .

It sounds to me that your Grub bootloader did not get initialized and loaded properly. . .  You can do this from a live disk.  Take a look at this answer in how to do it [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd)