# Failing to restart my laptop after installing Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and "bug: soft lockup" appears

Tags: boot, 18.04, cpu

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on my laptop Asus Vivobook s15, 8gb ram,i5-8256U CPU,256 Gb SSD.

After installation, this shows up:

[image: tty screen with messages]

I am new to using Ubuntu and I don't know what this means. Does anyone know what this means and how to solve it?

I tried powering off manually and then starting my laptop once again. But my booting screen freezes. Does this have anything to do with this image?

Answer (score 1):

I checked online and your laptop has the following graphics chip:
NVIDIA GeForce 940MX. This is important, since the issue is due to graphics drivers during bootup.

To resolve this issue, you need edit `/etc/default/grub`, and add `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau` at the end of the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable.

**1a. Access your Ubuntu root (`/`) directory (from Recovery Mode)**

To do this, boot into [Recovery Mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode). This is the preferred approach.

Open a terminal to enter enter commands as shown.

```
cd /
```

**1b. Access your Ubuntu root (`/`) directory (from Live CD)**

If you can't get into recovery mode, you can also boot up using a "Live CD" (i.e. the media you used to install Ubuntu) and mount the root partition where you installed Ubuntu. If you use this approach, click the "Try Ubuntu" button, launch the Disks application, click on your hard disk, click on the partition where you installed Ubuntu, and then mount that partition. The instructions below refer to this location as `<mount location>`.

Open a terminal to enter enter commands as shown.

```
cd <mount location>
```

**2. Edit grub**

```
cat etc/default/grub
sudo sed -i "s|splash|splash modprobe.blacklist=nouveau|g" etc/default/grub
cat etc/default/grub
```

**3a. Update Grub (from Recovery Mode)**

If you were able to boot into Recovery Mode, update grub...

```
sudo update-grub
```

**3b. Update Grub (from Live CD)**

If you booted using the Live CD, updating Grub is a little more complex. See [How do I run update-grub from a LiveCD?](https://askubuntu.com/a/145253/100356). Here is a summary of those instructions...

```
sudo mount --bind /dev <mount location>/dev
sudo mount --bind /sys <mount location>/sys
sudo mount --bind /proc <mount location>/proc
```

Check `mnt/etc/fstab` to see if have a separate Ubuntu boot partition.

```
cat mnt/etc/fstab
```

If you see an entry for `/boot` in mnt/etc/fstab, execute the following. (If you did a standard install, you probably will not need this).

```
sudo mount /dev/sdaX <mount location>/boot
```

...where `/dev/sdaX` is the device `/boot` points to in `mnt/etc/fstab`.

Then, update grub.

```
sudo chroot <mount location>
sudo update-grub
exit
```

**4. Reboot**

```
    Finally, reboot.
```

For reference the relevant section of your modified `/etc/default/grub` file should look something like this.

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=1
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE='hidden'
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash modprobe.blacklist=nouveau"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```