# Forgot to update GRUB config

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I downloaded kernel source code from https://kernel.org and compiled it with `make menuconfig`. I just copied result to `i forgot where i copied but im pretty sure that i copied it in right place because tutorial said me to do this`. And i rebooted my laptop, but i see, that it wont boot. Im going to `initramfs` every time i try to boot into ubuntu, because i forgot to update the GRUB config. Can i update the config, from for example LiveCD, and how do i do that?

Comment: [This should do it for you](https://askubuntu.com/a/145253/1091774) 

Comment: I do not understand "I just copied result to". You don't copy anything you use dpkg to install the compiled kernel. If you want to compile yourself, then I suggest you steal the kernel configuration from [the Ubuntu mainline PPA](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D) version of the same kernel.

Comment: yes i compiled for myself, just using the make.