# Can't boot into safemode to fix graphics

Tags: 22.04, amd-graphics, grub-efi

Just installed 22.04 on a new machine with a 5700g and I get a black screen once it boots. I was only able to install by launching the installer through safe mode.

Problem is, I can't get into safemode when booting the installation. I have to spam escape to get it in time to stop the launch, but then once I am at the menu hitting escape again takes me out to the GRUB CLI. From there I don't know how to boot into safemode and I can't find any info on booting into safemode from the CLI.

Is there a way to get back to the grub menu from there, or to boot into safemode from the CLI?

Comment: you just need to add "nomodeset" to kernel boot parameters

Comment: @Esther I did also add nomodeset to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT options, but for some reason it still wouldn't show the UI unless I went to recovery mode and then normal boot from there. Not entirely sure why.

Comment: Upon checking I spelled nomodeset wrong (nodemodeset). will update now and add that to the answer if it works

Comment: @Esther updated it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GRUB documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Overview.html#Overview) states that

> While in the menu, you can switch to the command-line mode, and
> vice-versa

but I was unable to find documentation for opening the menu from the CLI in the documentation.

Instead, I booted from the installation USB which I was able to get into safemode. From there I was able to mount my main hard-drive and edited `/etc/default/grub` changing `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` to give time enough time to hit the key once without spamming and enter the menu.

I also was able to add the `nomodeset` option to the variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in the same file, which let the graphics work properly when booting without recovery mode.

Then I followed [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd) to properly mount the relevant parts of my main disk and update-grub.

Then I was able to hit escape once without spamming because of the extra time, and enter recovery mode. I was also able to just boot regularly without a black screen because of the nomodeset option.