# Headless sever wont boot after dist upgrade from 20.04lts -> 22.04lts

Tags: boot, upgrade

I was upgrading old production server from 16.04Lts via ssh (only way I have access)
new piece of software we use required me to update to a newer dist

Upgrade went fine from 16.04lts to 18.04lts
18.04lts-20.04lts something went wrong mid way through
I followed a guide online which suggested to re run do-release-upgrade to complete the unfinished upgrade but instead it "started" to update to 22.04 lts

since that point server no longer boots
and only access i have is via rescue mode live system on same network

I 've followed guide similar to this : [How do I run update-grub from a LiveCD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd/145253#145253)

which let me mount and access my ubuntu partition and chroot into it

Ive tried to clean and reinstall any packages showing errors

reconfigure dpkg
upgrade grup, tried to reinstall grub

tried practically any guide i could find on here/google for fixing boot issues. (which may have caused further damage)

with no luck so far, and I am not sure how to proceed from here, I am not even sure what the problem could be.

Any help or tips on how to debug this would be much appreciated, and if need be I can post what ever logs

Thank you for your time

Comment: Without access to the boot up errors, it's hard/impossible to debug this. I would recommend backing up all important data and re-installing the OS to the latest stable version. What is the reason for upgrading?

Comment: server is used a dedicated server for Unreal Engine 5 project, which stated ubuntu 20.04lts as a requirement.

And I could post logs here, but would need to know what ones.

Comment: There is not enough information about the original error nor about your interruption to offer useful repair advice. It may be that your research and attempts to repair have indeed caused additional undetermined damage. We don't know the state of your system, we don't have a clear understanding of the damage. An interrupted release-upgrade is just about the worst problem that can befall your system, and is sometimes unrepairable. Advice: Clean-install Ubuntu 20.04 and rebuild your server. Restore your data (not applications) from your backups.